# How to export the data from menu component so that it can be used in the corresponding html component

Tags: angular

From the file menu.components.ts I need to export the data so that I can render it in menu.components.html.

I usually get confused when it comes to exporting the data inside the export `class MenuComponent implements OnInit` sometimes I see it being exported with colon and sometimes with equal to.

Shared folder

**dish.ts**

```
export class Dish {
        id: String;
        name: String;
        image: String;
        category: string;
```

Shared folder

**dishes.ts**

```
import { Dish } from './dish';

export const Dishes: Dish[] = [
    {
        id: '0',
        name: 'Uthappizza',
        image: '/assets/images/uthappizza.png',
```

**menu.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

    import { Dishes } from '../shared/dishes';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-menu',
      templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./menu.component.css']
    })
    export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {

      Dishes;

      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {
      }
    }
```

**menu.component.html**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
   <div class="title">
     {{.name}}
   </div>
   <div class='im'>
```

Answer (score 0):

In angular, the html template can only access fields and methods of the component class. So, you can create a component variable say

```
public dishes: Dish[] = Dishes // the one you imported
```

and in the html, use *ngFor to iterate over the `dishes` array which is a component variable and show them. You need to correct your html also. Please refer to the documentation for the syntax.

Comment: @guhawaf, did you try using component and did it work?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to expand upon @dileepkumar jami answer, because your HTML file had an error as well. Namely, `.name` would not do anything, because it doesn't reference an actual variable.

As an example of how to iterate over the dishes and display their names you would need the following.

1. In the component you need `public dishes: Dishes[] = Dishes`. This will assign your imported object to a component data member called `dishes`.
2. In the HTML file you need: `<div *ngFor="let dish of dishes">{{dish.name}}</div>` This will loop over the array of dishes you defined in the component and display the name of each dish in a new div.